# Python pandas: updating dataframe series values based on values contained in another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am using pandas with python and I have a dataframe `data`. I have another dataframe `missing_vals`. `missing_vals` contains a `field` column and a `key` column. The `field` column contains elements that correspond to names of the columns of `data` i.e `data.columns ~= missing_vals['field']`. The mapping, however, is not one-to-one (some entries in `missing_vals['field']` do not exist in `data.columns`. I did a set intersection operation to take care of that and got an output array `result` containing all the values that are both in `missing_vals['field']` and `data.columns`. Now I want to index into `data` using each element of `result`, check to see if that column contains the value corresponding to the element in `missing_vals['key']` and replace it with `NaN`. I tried using for-loops, but I know this is not the ideal way to do it. Is there a way to do it with vector/lambda operations or perhaps with other dataframe functions? I am new to pandas so I would really appreciate some help.

Here is my code so far:

`for i in range(len(result)):
    field = missing_vals['field'][i]
    for j in range(data[field].size):
        if (data[field][j] == missing_vals['key'][i]):
            data.replace(data[field][j], np.nan)`

Thanks

Comment: Please provide some sample data.  For example, data.head(10) and missing_vals.head(10).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really post sample input/output - these things are difficult explain verbally. Anyway, I think the second loop can be done away with entirely. You really just have to do.

```
field = missing_vals['field'][i]
data[field].replace(missing_vals['key'][i], np.nan)
```

The `replace` method replace all occurances with the replacement value and if there are none it does nothing. It's unnecessary to loop through the columns yourself to check if the value to be replaced is there. If you post representative examples of the data frames in question I can probably help you more.

Comment: Sorry, I'm sort of new to this. Next time I'll post some screenshots, thanks for the tip. Anyways, your suggestion worked! I appreciate the help.

Comment: Well you can edit the current question and then I can edit the answer. You can do it by screen shot or just by copy and pasting input/output from your interpreter. You could also vote me up if the answer helps :)